# Automapper and class hierarchy

Tags: c#, automapper, derived

Given the following sources:

```
public class SourceBase { public string TheString { get; set; } }
public class SourceDerived : SourceBase { }
```

and destinations:

```
public class DestBase { public string MyString { get; set; } }
public class DestDerived : DestBase { }
```

And this mapping:

```
  CreateMap<SourceBase, DestBase>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MyString, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.TheString))
    .Include<SourceDerived, DestDerived>();

  CreateMap<SourceDerived, DestDerived>();
  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();  // Exception is thrown here
```

However, this gives a mapping error saying MyString isn't mapped on DestDerived.  What gives?  Do I really need to repeat the mappings for base class properties in all derived types (I do have more than one subclass in my actual code).

EDIT:

The exact exception is *The following 1 properties on DestDerived could not be mapped:  MyString.  Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property on DestDerived*.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post:
http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/69ba514a521e9599

It works fine if you declare it like in the code below (using AutoMapper 1.1.0.188). I am not sure if this solves your problem.

```
var result = Mapper.CreateMap<SourceBase, DestBase>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MyString, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.TheString));
               //.Include<SourceDerived, DestDerived>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDerived, DestDerived>();
            var source = new SourceDerived();
            var destDerived = new DestDerived();
            source.TheString = "teststring";
            var mapResult = Mapper.Map<SourceBase, DestBase>(source, destDerived).MyString;
            Console.WriteLine(mapResult);
```

Comment: No this doesn't work for us.  Its really odd too that if you call Mapper.Map(source, typeof(SourceDerived), typeof(DestDerived)) then your sample code fails.  No exception, but no mapping is done either.

Comment: We are also calling `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`.  I think you'll find that if you add that call right after you setup your mappings, you'll get the exception mentioned in my post.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am sorry I couldn't be of any help!

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure why your example works, but other calls to Map don't!